# Rails update_attributes not updating nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

In my Rails application, each of my groups has_many :expenses. Each expense has_many :shares. I have successfully set up a nested form which allows me to create expenses and shares simultaneously. However, when I use the same form to try to edit an expense, the validation that I set up to ensure that the sum of all shares is equal to the expense total amount is failing.

Here's my update method from my controller:

```
def update
  @expense = Expense.find(params[:id])
  @group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
  if @expense.update_attributes(params[:expense])
    redirect_to @group
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

In my model files, I have stated accepts_nested_attributes_for :shares in expense.rb, and added :shares_attributes to its attr_accessible list.

The validation I set up in expense.rb that is failing is:

```
def shares_must_equal_total_amount
    if self.shares.sum(:amount) != self.amount
        errors.add(:shares, " must equal expense amount")
    end
end
```

What I am most confused about is that if I

```
puts @expense.amount and 
@expense.shares.sum(:amount)
```

in the else clause of my update method (before the render 'edit'), the two values are different. But, in the params[:shares_attributes], the individual share amounts are clearly being updated and passing validation. So, for some reason @expense.shares is not being updated when I call if @expense.update_attributes(params[:expense]).

What am I missing here? Thanks for the help.